# Power Query: Combine Item Number with Month and Year from Date Column"

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a column called item number and date I want a new column with item number merged with month and year from the corresponding date of item number can someone help me with the power query in the transform data

[itemnumber] & [report_date].[MonthNo] & [report_date].[Year]
also tried this Text.From([itemnumber]) & Text.From(Date.Month([report_date])) & Text.From(Date.Year([report_date]))

editor says Token',' expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula works fine assuming your columns are properly named and report_date column is type date

add column ... custom column ...

```
= Text.From([itemnumber]) & Text.From(Date.Month([report_date])) & Text.From(Date.Year([report_date]))
```

[image]